# What is the difference between "target" and "foil" in experimental design?

Tags: terminology, experimental-psychology, experiment-design, terms

What is the difference between

> "target"

and

> "foil"

in experimental design in psychology?  And how is a foil different from a distractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, experimental designs in psychology contain a target participant (who receives the experimental manipulation) and then also other types, such as:

control: no intervention, or a different intervention
confederate: fake participant (actor, or often research assistant)
observer: in social influence paradigms

perhaps foil is a confederate. Hard to know without you providing the source.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference between a "distractor" and a "foil"?

Comment: See recent answer

Answer (score 2):

A [target](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199534067.001.0001/acref-9780199534067-e-8270) is:

> A stimulus that a research participant or subject is searching for or
>   trying to concentrate on, and that in research is often accompanied by
>   distractors.

And a [foil](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199534067.001.0001/acref-9780199534067-e-3226) is:

> In research methodology, another name for a distractor.

For example, in a multiple choice question, the correct answer is the "target", and the rest are "foils" or distractors.  This is similar to a [police lineup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_lineup), where the suspect is the "target", and the rest are "foils" or fillers.  "Foil" and "distractor" are synonyms.